# For two sequences of equally likely events, is the probability of their intersection the same?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{A_n\}$ and $\{B_n\}$ be two sequences of events.

Assume that $P(A_n)=P(B_n)$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Then, is it true that $P(\bigcap A_n) = P(\bigcap B_n)$?

It "seems" that each since each event has the same probability, the intersections should also have the same probability, but how does one prove/disprove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toss a fair coin twice. Let $A_1$ be the event head on first, $A_2$ the event head on second. Let $B_1$ be the event first and second match, $B_2$ the event they don't match. All of these have probability $1/2$.

Note that $A_1\cap A_2$ has probability $1/4$, while $B_1\cap B_2$ has probability $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, $B_1 \subset B_2$ and  $P(A_1) = P(B_1) \ne 0$,  $P(A_2) = P(B_2)$.

Then $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$ but $P(B_1 \cap B_2) = P(B_1) \ne 0$

Answer (score 0):

It's true if $A_n$ and $B_n$ are decreasing.

A counter example is $A_n=\{X_n\in [0,\frac{1}{n}]\}$ and $B_n=\{X_n\in [n,n+\frac{1}{n}]\}$

Comment: Your counter example would need P(X=0)\gt 0$

Comment: Yes of course, thank you to precise it.